# How to fix 'Rugged::ReferenceError: revspec 'origin/master' not found' on Gitlab CI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to setup pronto for Gitlab CI, locally everything works fine, but when pronto runs on Gitlab CI "Rugged::ReferenceError: revspec 'origin/master' not found" error raising

```
cache:
  paths:
    - vendor/

services:
  - name: mysql:8.0
    command: ["mysqld", "--character-set-server=utf8mb4", "--collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci", "--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password"]

variables:
  MYSQL_DATABASE: $MYSQL_DATABASE
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: $MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
  DB_USERNAME: $DB_USERNAME
  DB_HOST: $DB_HOST
  DISABLE_SPRING: 1


before_script:
  - cp config/database.yml.example config/database.yml
  - apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y -qq cmake
  - gem install bundler --no-document
  - bundle check || bundle install --path vendor --jobs $(nproc)  "${FLAGS[@]}"

spec:
  script:
    - bundle exec rspec

pronto:
  script:
    - bundle exec pronto run -c origin/master --exit-code
```

```
Rugged::ReferenceError: revspec 'origin/master' not found
  vendor/ruby/2.6.0/gems/pronto-0.10.0/lib/pronto/git/repository.rb:87:in `merge_base'
  vendor/ruby/2.6.0/gems/pronto-0.10.0/lib/pronto/git/repository.rb:87:in `merge_base'
  vendor/ruby/2.6.0/gems/pronto-0.10.0/lib/pronto/git/repository.rb:17:in `diff'
  vendor/ruby/2.6.0/gems/pronto-0.10.0/lib/pronto.rb:62:in `run'
  vendor/ruby/2.6.0/gems/pronto-0.10.0/lib/pronto/cli.rb:66:in `block in run'
  vendor/ruby/2.6.0/gems/pronto-0.10.0/lib/pronto/cli.rb:64:in `chdir'
  vendor/ruby/2.6.0/gems/pronto-0.10.0/lib/pronto/cli.rb:64:in `run'
  vendor/ruby/2.6.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
  vendor/ruby/2.6.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
  vendor/ruby/2.6.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
  vendor/ruby/2.6.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/base.rb:466:in `start'
  vendor/ruby/2.6.0/gems/pronto-0.10.0/bin/pronto:6:in `<top (required)>'
  vendor/ruby/2.6.0/bin/pronto:23:in `load'
  vendor/ruby/2.6.0/bin/pronto:23:in `<top (required)>'
```

I expect to run pronto on gitlab without Exceptions

Comment: The error message says "revspec 'origin/master' not found". Do you have a remote named "origin"? Can you include the output of `git remote -v` in your question please?

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if this is the best solution, but this worked for me:

- In your gitlab repo, go to settings -> CI/CD
- In the section General pipelines -> Git strategy for pipelines, mark the option `git clone` instead of `git fetch`
  [image: git clone]
- I also had to add a `git fetch` command just above the `pronto` invocation:

```
pronto:
  script:
    - git fetch
    - bundle exec pronto run -c origin/master --exit-code
```